# app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000); (Object) set ^ TypeError: app.set is not a function

Tags: node.js

D:\Project\example\app.js:17

```
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

> TypeError: app.set is not a function

Comment: Kindly add the full code of the file which throws the error so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting all possible solution because you have not mentioned your code in question

try to add

```
var port = config.PORT || 8081; // set our port

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port); // shoutout to the user
});
```

you are getting error because you are trying to `set` port but you have to use `app.listen`

and also the second reason of error could be you have done mistake in exporting app

you have to export app like this

`module.exports = app;`